# Write a function to find indices of first two largest numbers

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

So I was asked to solve this question during an online interview and failed. I was immediately rejected.
I'm trying to figure out what was wrong with my algorithm.

> **Two Largest Numbers**
>
> In the programming language of your choice write a function that takes an array of integers and returns the indices of the first two largest numbers. Document any special behavior around edge cases if there are any. The function should have a running time of `O(N)` where N is the length of the array and `O(1)` additional space.

I wrote this method to sort the numbers in C#:

```cs
int[] sortArrayIndicies(int[] numbers)
{
   int high = int.MinValue;
   int secondHigh = int.MinValue;

   for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
   {
      if (numbers[i] > numbers[high])
      {
         secondHigh = high;
         high = i;
      }
      else if (numbers[i] > numbers[secondHigh])
      {
         secondHigh = i;
      }
   }

   return new[] {high, secondHigh};
}
```

As for documenting special behaviour for edge cases, I was responded with the following:

> The high and second high variables have been initialized to min int value instead of the default value of zero for cases where the numbers are negative.
>   Complexity is `O(N)`.

Where did I go wrong? I know time complexity is `O(N)` because i'm iterating through the entire list, and space complexity is `O(1)` because of the small (fixed) amount of space for the high and second high variables.

Comment: how can the indices `high` and `secondHigh` be initialized to `int.MinValue`?. Also, in such situations you could ask them for clarifications on how to handle duplicate highest number. Your thought process on this one is right. It's just the implementation that went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment is an indirect way of saying that your code is going to crash for any non-empty input, because during the initial iteration `numbers[high]` is going to be an equivalent of referencing `numbers[int.MinValue]`.

The comment suggests that you initialize both values to `0`. I think you could go further, and initialize the values to `0` and `1` or to `1` and `0`, depending on which of the two initial numbers is larger. After that you'd start iterating from index `2`. Of course you would need to ensure that the array has at least two elements.

Another special case that your program should consider is when two largest numbers are equal to each other, as in `{1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3}`. In this case both `high` and `secondHigh` would have the same value, so your program should return `{2, 5}`.